# cannot get utf8 icon with charAt js

Tags: javascript

let a=[""] ;
let b=""

console.log(a[0],b,b.charAt(0))

""
""
"�"

this charAt prints questions mark ... can someone enlighten me how to get utf8 icon with charAt in a string

Comment: Can you use the spread operator of es6 in your project?

Comment: but it only works for array, right? I just want to get urf8 icon in a string by s.charAt(s.length-1)

Comment: The spread operator works on anything that is iterable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emojis are represented using multiple bytes:

```js
let b=""
console.log(b.length)
```

With `charAt` you only get one part of the emoji.

With [`codePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) you can get the:

> a non-negative integer that is the Unicode code point value at the given position.

You however need to know where the emojii starts at, because the index itself still refers to the bytes:

```js
let b=""
console.dir(String.fromCodePoint(b.codePointAt(0)));
console.dir(String.fromCodePoint(b.codePointAt(2)));
```

You could split your string using the spread operator `...`  and then access the visible char in question using the index. This works because the iterator uses the code points and not individual bytes.

```js
let b="testtest"

function splitStringByCodePoint(str) {
  return [...str]
}

console.log(splitStringByCodePoint(b)[5])
```

But that won't work with emojis like  because those consist of  + byte(s) representing the variation (color).

```js
let b=""
console.log(b.length)
function splitStringByCodePoint(str) {
  return [...str]
}

console.log(splitStringByCodePoint(b))
console.log(String.fromCodePoint(b.codePointAt(0)));
console.log(String.fromCodePoint(b.codePointAt(2)));
```

If you want to support all emojis you currently need to write your own parser or look for a library that does that.